# Is there a way to view time logged during a status in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jql

I'd like to view how much time is logged on issues while they are in a certain status, and we have scriptrunner and tempo. Is this possible?

I was thinking something along the lines of this JQL, but it is showing the total time logged and not the time during that status.

JQL: `status was "Pending Review" and issuefunction in aggregateExpression("Time spent during code review", "timespent.sum()")`

Comment: Have you tried Wakatime?  https://wakatime.com  Not confident this would be a good answer, but I think there's a Jira integration for this tool.